# What is this pip config output?

Tags: python, environment-variables, path, package-management, pip

I have to install and configure Python 3.8.10 on a Windows 7 machine and I'm getting this output for `pip config -v list`:

```
C:\Users\Username>pip config -v list
For variant 'global', will try loading 'C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\Username\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.
ini'
For variant 'site', will try loading 'c:\program files\python38\pip.ini'
:env:.target='C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages'
```

What is the last line and how can I modify or delete this `:env:.target`? I tried the following to no avail:

```
pip config unset .target
pip config unset user.taret
pip config unset env.target
pip config unset :env:.target
```

This whole `pip` package comes across like a pile of guesswork as there is *absolutely* no information available even in the official docs or man pages (i.e. `pip config -help`). Isn't there a proper, detailed documentation including a complete list of all possible commands as one would expect for such a widely used package?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the `:env:` indicator means the value is being determined by an environment variable. In my case, that was `PIP_INDEX_URL`, and by [unsetting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103555/how-do-i-unset-a-variable-at-the-command-line) it, I was able to resolve this issue. Additional information about the environment variables pip uses is available in the [configuration documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/).